# Scala define annotation wrapping another annotation

Tags: scala, newrelic

I'm currently using Java's New Relic agent to track some metrics in my Scala code. I've realized that for all scenarios where I want to track stuff I always need to do the same; so I'd like to reach a solution that is DRY so I avoid duplicating the same logic multiple times. And there are a lot of methods that should be tracked.

Basically a method I want to track looks like this right now:

```scala
  @Trace(dispatcher = true)
  override def get(token: Token, id: String): SomeResponse = {
    NewRelic.addCustomParameter("customerId", token.customerId)
    NewRelic.addCustomParameter("apiKey", token.getMaskedApiKey)
    // rest of the code...
  }
```

Is there a way in Scala to define a wrapper for the `@Trace` + the `addCustomParameter` calls? That way I can collapse 3 lines into just one. Ideally, I'd achieve this by using a new annotation but it's not strictly necessary.

I'm using Scala 2.13.4 (and cannot upgrade)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use the `Weave` class within the New Relic agent API to weave any methods within any classes that you want to `@Trace` annotate or call `addCustomParameter` within. There are some example weaves for Scala classes here: https://github.com/newrelic-experimental/newrelic-java-http4s

Essentially this would allow you to add those agent API calls to any method that is apart of the class you are weaving. Basically you define your own instrumentation class that gets applied to the originating class at runtime. Weaving is basically class bytecode manipulation.